# Describing the set of elements that are in at least one of the sets A or B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

**Textbook problem:** Use unions, intersections, and complements to express the set of elements that are in at least one of the sets $A$ or $B$, where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the set $\Omega$.

**My solution:** Using juxtaposition to denote intersections my solution is $AB^c \, \cup \, BA^c \, \cup \, AB$ because I think it's the set of elements in $A$ but not $B$, in $B$ but not $A$, or in both $A$ and $B$.

**Textbook solution:** $(A\,\cup B)\,\cap\,(A\,\cap\,B)^c$ which I believe to be equivalent to $AB^c \, \cup \, BA^c$ using de Morgan's laws.

**Question:** Is the textbook solution a mistake or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Note that this is not for a course; I'm self-studying.  This is an appendix problem on set notation and operations from an introduction to probability textbook. This particular appendix is preliminary material for the text proper.

Comment: ??.... The set of elements that are in at least one of A,B is $A\cup B$. But $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c$ is the set of elements that are in A or  in B but not in both A and B.

Comment: The textbook answer gives the set of objects that is either in A or in B but not both.  Exactly one of A or B.  Your answer is equivalent to $A\cup B$ albeit in a more complicated formation.  That is those objects in at least one of A and B.

Comment: @DougM Right, I agree.  So am I misunderstanding the textbook problem?

Comment: @DougM So the textbook is accidentally answering the "exactly" question instead of the "at least" question which is the one they asked?

Comment: If the textbook is really asking the question you say it is asking, and really giving the answer you say it is giving, it is time to find a better textbook.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's a direct quote.   Perhaps it's listed on the errata page, but the link to it is currently down.